# Show nearest neighborhood decoding is the same as maximum likelihood decoding in the following case

Tags: probability, coding-theory

I don't see what's wrong about my solution. The question is as below

Show that for every code C over an alphabet of size $q,$ the nearest neighborhood decoding is the same as maximum likelihood decoding w.r.t. memoryless $q-$ary symmetric channel with crossover probability $p<1-(1/q).$

Here's my thoughts: Just like binary symmetric channel, $d(x,c) = i$ if and only if $$P(x~ received \mid ~c~ sent) = p^{i} (1-p)^{n-i},$$ but somehow this idea has nothing to do with the relation we have in the question, so there must be something wrong... Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

The function in the case $q=2:$
$$
p^i(1-p)^{n-i}=p^n(p/(1-p))^i=p^n r^i
$$
is monotone decreasing with $i$ as soon as $p<1/2,$ which gives $r<1,$ thus *under this assumption* the probability of an error with smaller hamming weight is more than the probability of an error pattern with larger hamming weight, so minimum distance decoding is ML decoding.

Similarly for the monotonicity property to hold (and for ML to be the same as minimum distance decoding) in the case of the $q-$ary symmetric channel one must have the inequality $p<(q-1)/q.$ I leave it to you to work out the details via an obvious summation over the nonzero symbols.